# How to call a field in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, honeypot

I have a `comments` model, and within that model, I have a field called `:honey`.

In the view, `:honey` is a hidden form field.

In the controller, when the form posts I want it to redirect to the home page if `:honey` is filled out.

How do I call that specific field in my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about when your form posts back to your action, you should be checking `params`. Either look in your logs or use [`binding.pry`](https://github.com/pry/pry) and look for the key and value you're expecting.

It will probably be `params[:comment][:honey]`.